opening book via CLI in new Kindle app?
With the Kindle Classic app it was possible to open a book in Kindle by locating the azw file and running open "mybook.azw" in terminal. Does anybody know how to do that in the new Kindle app for Mac?

I assume you tried, and it doesn't work anymore?

Also, does the "new" app open the file if you locate the .azw in Finder and double-click it?

I don't seem to be able to find azw files in the new file structure, I can only see multiple (multiple per book?) azw9.res files which I am not able to open via CLI.
